# Allow redirection to a page only at a specific time frame in php

Tags: php, html, datetime, session, redirect

I need some help with my college project. I am trying to make php website for online exam. Here, The examination time is stored in database. Now the student will only be allowed to start exam when he/she starts exam within the first 15 minutes of the exam. Here is my code for time calculation.

```php
<?php 
     $xmtime=$rows['exam_dt_time'];


     if (time() <= strtotime($xmtime) and time() <= strtotime("+15 minutes", $xmtime)) {   
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('Ready for Exam!');
        </script>";
    }
    else
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('Exam cannot be started');
        window.location.href='std_home.php';
        </script>";
    } ?>
```

The time check is not working properly. I cannot figure out what is wrong. Please help. Thanks in advance. I am trying to be clear and precise as possible. Please pardon any mistake made.

Comment: The second parameter to strtotime has to be a unix timestamp. Now since you are using `strtotime($xmtime)` in the first comparison, I assume that $xmtime does _not_ contain a unix timestamp, right?

Comment: Also you don't need both I don't think.  Why not just `if(time() <= strtotime("+15 minutes", strtotime($xmtime)))`?

Comment: Thanks AbraCadaver, I did what you said but now all exams with future dates can be accessed.